# Two loops in one table

Tags: php, html

I need to insert two loops in one table, but I have a problem.

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Position</th>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>
<?php
for ($x=1; $x<=2; $x++) {
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $x ?></td>
<?php
}
?>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$id = $row['id']; 
$name = $row['name']; 
?>

<td><?php echo $name ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

But the result is:

http://prntscr.com/6m9v25

One name is in the wrong position.

Comment: There is no such thing as "loops in a table"

Comment: Stop pointing that gun at me and explain what the frak you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

Just put while loop into for loop.

// Code goes here

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Position</th>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>
<?php
for ($x=1; $x<=2; $x++) {
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $x ?></td>

<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$id = $row['id']; 
$name = $row['name']; 
?>

<td><?php echo $name ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Position</th>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>
<?php
$x = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$id = $row['id']; 
$name = $row['name']; 
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $x ?></td>
<td><?php echo $name ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
$x++
}
?>
</table>
```

Try This Code!! (Edited Again!)

Comment: your out put is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1kVrl1aySvLWWNnaXU5MGdkN0E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this $x += 1; to this $x++. :D

Comment: Yeah they are one and the same